# How to make jAutoCalc work on dynamically Added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Let me explain what i'm doing : i have a Orders table where i can add, delete and edit the client's orders. Everything works fine for the add and delete. But when it comes to edit i have some trouble. What i'm doing is pulling data from the DATABASE (using codeigniter) and displaying them to the edit modal so that i can then edit them if the clients wishes so. The Client's infos(name,adresse,state..etc) load fine but when i load his orders with the products and dynamically add them using (jQuery, ajax), the Item total field ( which calculates the sum of the product orders * its unit price using the jAutoCalc plugin) doesn't seems to work. The plugin works just fine when i'm not adding dynamically the data. Is there a way to fix this or add something that will make it work? here's my code

```
var thehtml = ''
for(i=0; i<data[1].length; i++){
    thehtml += 
              '<tr class=cmd'+id+'>'+
                 '<td>'+
                    '<select name="products" id="productselect>"'+
                        '<option data-price="39" value="1">Knife</option>'+
                        '<option data-price="3" value=2">Bottle</option>'+
                        '<option data-price="4" value="3">Pen</option>'+
                    '</select>'+
                 '</td>'+
                 '<td><input type="text" name="qty" value="39"></td>'+
                 '<td><input type="text" name="price" value="33"></td>'+
                 '<td><input readonly type="text" jAutoCalc="{qty} * {price}"/>'+ /// THIS DOESNT WORK IT'S DYNAMICALLY ADDED !!!!
                 '<button type="button" name="add" value="Add" class="tr_clone_remove  btn btn-danger">Remove</button>'+'</td>'+
              '</tr>;';
$(thehtml).insertAfter(itemselement);
```

Please note that everything works find in non dynamically added elements. But whenever i added these table dynamically nothing works ! please help me fix it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're adding elements to the DOM after the `jAutoCalc` has already been initialized, the plugin is not aware that there are new elements. You need to initialize the `jAutoCalc` on these elements.

You could simply do something like this

```
$(thehtml).jAutoCalc();
```

after you appended the new rows.

If that doesn't work, try

```
$('form').jAutoCalc();
```

It all depends on your HTML structure but you just need to reinitialize it.